# Is two cameras equivalent to Stereo camera setup?

Tags: computer-vision, cameras, 3d-reconstruction

I have two webcams, which are mounted close together. I plan to use them to find out the true depth of certain pixels of images. Suppose I use a standard multi camera calibration setup and find out the relative orientation of one with respect to the other camera, can it perform as well as a stereo camera setup for depth estimation? What are the challenges typically? How accurate must the calibration be?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use two camera the same as using single stereo camera for depth perception.
Step on calibration camera for two camera and stereo camera is same.

Answer (score 1):

The challenges you are going to face is more how to mount the cameras and find the relative positions between them (also the rotation). You can find a lot of designs for mounts for the cameras, also 3D printers' designs. The calibration is pretty similar to the one for one camera chess pattern etc. There are also a lot of tutorials explaining how you should proceed. Have fun!